# Redirect from nc & copy server output

Tags: networking, netcat, tee

I have an output from server: `nc 192.168.1.170 10001`

Also I have 2 programs which works like clients.

I want them to be able to get the same data from server. 
So I need to create one more server, copy of origin, with the same output.
Or another solution, I just want the programs get the same data

For one: `nc 192.168.1.170 10001 | nc -l -p 14888`

For 2 programs: `nc 192.168.1.170 10001 | tee nc -l -p 14889 |nc -l -p 14888`

-- not working

How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is with your `tee` command. Its parameters are files, not a command.

With `bash` you can use this:

```
nc 192.168.1.170 10001 | tee >(nc -l -p 14889) | nc -l -p 14888
```

Here `>(command)` is a pseudo-file which is actually a pipe to `command`'s input.

Comment: Nice. But nc is not working.. Can you help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335615/how-to-redirect-output-from-external-server-to-local-netcat

Comment: I tested it with `echo $'GET /\r\n\r\n'  | nc google.com 80 | tee >(nc -l 14889) | nc -l 14888` and I do get a copy of Google's answer on ports 14888 and 14889.

Comment: nc 192.168.1.170 10001 has continuous output.. may be this is a reason?

Comment: @user7365441 I have just tested this with a continuous output sent my my own server (`for ((i=0; ; i++)) do echo $i; done | nc -l ...`) and it works

Comment: @user7365441 Hmmm, wait, you happen tu use the original version of netcat. I'm using the OpenBSD version (`netcat-openbsd` package on Debian/Ubuntu). Maybe is this the reason why it works for me and not for you? Are you able to test with the OpenBSD version?

Comment: @user7365441 I have test with the traditional version of `netcat` and it works too.

Comment: I understand the problem:
make server: nc 192.168.1.170 10001 | nc -l -p 10001 //server terminal.
after I run my program, and in the server terminal some message appears and everything stopped. some response which broke  nc 192.168.1.170 10001 | nc -l -p 10001

Comment: WOW! I just need to wait longer! (the data comes from detector).
Tnank you man!

Comment: @user7365441 You're welcome. You may want to delete your other question now.